# use apacite package to generate reference, but the Heading style is not right, also it had a (Chapter head)* before it

Tags: apacite

Using `apacite` package to generate reference, but the Heading style is not right, also it had a (Chapter head)* before it.
The `.tex` contents:

```latex
\bibliography{myreference}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

The results are:

[image]

But I don't want here shows the (Chapter head)*  what's the hell of this? I don't know how come this shows here? And I want the Reference heading style just like this

[image]

Is there anyone can help me with this? I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Unfortunately, if you don't give us more information nobody can do anything but guess how to help you.  Please provide a minimum working example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497 for help on a minimal working example.  Also, try ctrl-F for "Chapter head"; it's not normally in there, so you've done something to make that happen.